# Consulta dinamica em um List

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, reflexão

Como aplicar um filtro em um objeto `List` genérico usando Lambda?

Eu sei que com *Reflection* eu posso obter um array com os nomes das propriedades do meu objeto e através do próprio *Reflection* recuperar a propriedade do objeto a partir do seu nome porem não sei como passar esse array e comparar os valores das propriedades dentro do Lambda.

Comment: Você já tem algum código pronto para colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: Talvez se você der um exemplo da aplicação seria mais fácil de compreender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A intensão de realizar uma consulta dinâmica em List era montar um form que exibiria a List em um DataGridView e realizaria uma consulta em todos os atributos dos objetos da List, sendo que a List dentro do form poderia conter um objeto qualquer. A solução apresentada pelo Mateus se mostrou viável, porem quando apresentei para o resto da equipe encontramos alguns problemas dentre eles:

- Quando um objeto possui outro objeto como atributo;
- Não seria possível personalizar a consulta, ex: limitar os campos os atributos a serem usados.

Apos bater cabeça com a equipe por 2 horas optei pela seguinte abordagem: Uma interface chamada "IListaAuxiliar" com um método chamado "FiltrarLista" que será implementado por todas as classes que usarem o form de consulta. Esse por sua vês também possuirá um atributo da mesma interface. Assim ao chamar o form passamos o objeto (Aplicacao_BLL por exemplo) e chamamos o o método FiltrarLista sem parâmetros para obter a lista completa. Depois é só guardar o termo da pesquisa digitado pelo usuário e filtrar novamente. As chamadas ao método FiltrarLista não são cumulativas pois agem sobre uma lista inalterada guardada dentro do objeto Aplicacao_BLL. Segue abaixo o código da interface e do objeto.

```
public class Aplicacao : Objeto_DTL
{
    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }

    private string _Nome;
    public string Nome
    {
        get { return _Nome; }
        set { _Nome = value; }
    }

    private List<Versao> _versao;
    public List<Versao> Versao
    {
        get { return _versao; }
        set { _versao = value; }
    }    
}

public interface IListaAuxiliar
{
    List<Object> FiltrarLista(string valor);
}

public class Aplicacao_BLL : IListaAuxiliar
{
    private List<Aplicacao> _lista;

    public List<Object> FiltrarLista(string valor)
    {
        var lTemp = _lista.Cast<Object>().Where(
                x => (x as Aplicacao).ID.Value.ToString().Contains(valor)
                    || (x as Aplicacao).Nome.Value.ToString().Contains(valor)
                    || (x as Aplicacao).Descricao.Value.ToString().Contains(valor)
                    || (x as Aplicacao).Criacao.Value.ToString().Contains(valor)
            );

        return lTemp.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você também pode utilizar as propriedades dos objetos e chamar métodos dos objetos, no link que eu passei tem um exemplo disso, depois edito a minha resposta somente para complementar!

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma pequena adaptação do [How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries (C# and Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637(v=vs.100).aspx).

Para ficar mais fácil de entender, vou criar a classe `Cliente`.

```cs
public class Cliente {

    public string Nome { get; set;}
    public int RG { get; set;}
    public int CPF { get; set;}

    public Cliente () : this ("", 0, 0) { }

    public Cliente(string nome, int rg, int cpf) {
        this.Nome = nome;
        this.RG = rg;
        this.CPF = cpf;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Nome + "\t" + RG + "\t" + CPF + "\n";
    }

}
```

Após criar os clientes, farei um filtro para retornar aqueles com **Nome** igual a *Mario* ou que tenha o **CPF** igual a *100*, feito isso vou ordená-los pelo **RG**, a expressão ficaria assim:

```
clientes.Where(cliente => cliente.Nome == "Mario" || cliente.CPF == 100)
        .OrderBy(cliente => cliente.RG)
```

Para criá-la dinamicamente, você pode fazer desse jeito:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // cria os clientes
        Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente("Mario", 963, 222);
        Cliente cliente2 = new Cliente("Carlos", 183, 444);
        Cliente cliente3 = new Cliente("Pedro", 722, 666);
        Cliente cliente4 = new Cliente("Mario", 737, 888);
        Cliente cliente5 = new Cliente("Maria", 159, 100);
        Cliente cliente6 = new Cliente("Carla", 194, 240);
        Cliente cliente7 = new Cliente("Mario", 10, 19);

        // adiciona os clientes em uma lista
        List<Cliente> listClientes = new List<Cliente>();
        listClientes.Add(cliente1);
        listClientes.Add(cliente2);
        listClientes.Add(cliente3);
        listClientes.Add(cliente4);
        listClientes.Add(cliente5);
        listClientes.Add(cliente6);
        listClientes.Add(cliente7);

        // recupera o IQueryable da lista de clientes
        IQueryable<Cliente> queryableData = listClientes.AsQueryable<Cliente>();

        // cria o parâmetro a ser utilizado na consulta
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Cliente), "cliente");

        // expressão 'cliente.Nome == "Mario"'
        Expression column = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(Cliente).GetProperty("Nome"));
        Expression value = Expression.Constant("Mario");
        Expression expr = Expression.Equal(column, value);

        // expressão 'cliente.CPF == 100'
        column = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(Cliente).GetProperty("CPF"));
        value = Expression.Constant(100, typeof(int));
        Expression expr2 = Expression.Equal(column, value);

        // expressão '(cliente.Nome == "Mario" || cliente.CPF == 100)'
        Expression predicateBody = Expression.OrElse(expr, expr2);

        // expressão 'queryableData.Where(cliente => 
        // (cliente.Nome == "Mario" || cliente.CPF == 100))'
        MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
            queryableData.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Cliente, bool>>(predicateBody, 
                                                   new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

        // expressão 'cliente.RG'
        Expression expr3 = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(Cliente).GetProperty("RG")); 

        // expressão 'whereCallExpression.OrderBy(cliente => cliente.RG)'
        MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "OrderBy",
            new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType, typeof(int) },
            whereCallExpression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Cliente, int>>(expr3, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

        // cria e executa a query
        IQueryable<Cliente> results = queryableData.Provider
                                      .CreateQuery<Cliente>(orderByCallExpression);

        // imprime resultado
        Console.WriteLine("Nome\tRG\tCPF");
        foreach (Cliente cliente in results)
            Console.Write(cliente.ToString());
    }

}
```

O resultado é:

```
Nome    RG      CPF
Mario   10      19
Maria   159     100
Mario   737     888
Mario   963     222
```

Você também pode criar um método genérico:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> Find<T>(List<T> list, string column, object value, 
                                    string columnOrder)
{
    // recupera o IQueryable da lista
    IQueryable<T> queryable = list.AsQueryable<T>();

    // cria o parâmetro a ser utilizado na consulta
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "param");

    // expressão 'param.column == value'
    Expression columnExp = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(T).GetProperty(column));
    Expression valueExp = Expression.Constant(value);
    Expression expr = Expression.Equal(columnExp, valueExp);

    // expressão 'queryable.Where(param => param.column == value)'
    MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { queryable.ElementType },
        queryable.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expr, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

    // expressão 'param.columnOrder'
    Expression expr2 = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(T).GetProperty(columnOrder));

    // expressão 'whereCallExpression.OrderBy(param => param.columnOrder)'
    MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "OrderBy",
        new Type[] { queryable.ElementType, expr2.Type },
        whereCallExpression,
        Expression.Lambda(expr2, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

    // cria e executa a query
    IQueryable<T> results = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderByCallExpression);

    return results;
}
```

Para utilizá-lo, informe os parâmetros conforme demonstrado abaixo:

```
IQueryable<Cliente> results = Find(listClientes, "Nome", "Mario", "CPF");
```

Resultando em:

```
Nome    RG  CPF
Mario   10  19
Mario   963 222
Mario   737 888
```

Caso você precise acessar mais atributos do objeto ou chamar algum método, você pode fazer assim:

```
// exemplo base, considerando que a classe Cliente possui o atributo Endereco,
// que por sua vez possui o atributo Logradouro, teríamos algo assim:
// param.Endereco.Logradouro.ToLower() == "avenida paulista"
// que pode ser feito conforme mostrado abaixo

[...]

// cria o parâmetro a ser utilizado na consulta
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Cliente), "param");

// expressão 'param.Endereco'
Expression columnEndereco = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(Cliente).GetProperty("Endereco"));
// expressão 'param.Endereco.Logradouro'
Expression columnLogradouro = Expression.Property(columnEndereco, typeof(Endereco)
    .GetProperty("Logradouro"));
// expressão 'param.Endereco.Logradouro.ToLower()'
Expression columnToLower = Expression.Call(columnLogradouro, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower"));
Expression columnValue = Expression.Constant("avenida paulista");
// expressão 'param.Endereco.Logradouro.ToLower() == "avenida paulista"'
Expression expr = Expression.Equal(columnToLower, columnValue);

[...]
```

Creio que com isso você já consegui ter uma base para fazer o que você precisa.

**Extras**

[Expression Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression_members(v=vs.90).aspx)
[How to a compose a Linq Expression to call OrderBy on a set of entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219404)
[Métodos genéricos (Guia de Programação em C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

Comment: Esse seu código pare ser o que eu estou querendo, eu vou tentar usa-lo e retorno assim que puder.

Comment: @Mateus Esta resposta está perfeita. Parabéns! Eu fiquei meio perdido ao tentar alterar utilizar com .ToString().Contains(filtro). Será que poderia me ajudar? Qq dica serve. Valew!

Answer (score 0):

Deixa eu ver se entendi: você quer filtrar um objeto List genérico (List) usando lambda? Por exemplo, dada uma lista de números, retornar somente os pares; ou então, dada uma lista de objetos do tipo Pessoa, retornar somente os elementos onde Pessoa.Sexo seja igual a "F"? Se for isso, não precisa de reflection, basta você usar o método Where:

```
// Para List<Int32> filtrando somente os pares
lista.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList()

// Para List<Pessoa> filtrando somente pessoas do sexo feminino.
lista.Where(x => x.Sexo == "F").ToList()
```

Comment: Não exatamente pois da forma como você exemplificou eu tenho que conhecer o objeto dentro da List em tempo de projeto, porem o objeto dentro da List poderá ser alterado. Ex: Em um momento ele receberá instancias de pessoas e noutro instancias de de produtos. A ideia é fazer uma tela de consulta padrão na qual eu passo um List e ela filtra todas as propriedades a partir de um paramento informado.